# How to pass parameter to the table's datasource with Telerik Reporting?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik, report, reporting, telerik-reporting

I have a table on my Telerik report where I want to pass parameters with the table's data source. I also have a report datasource with parameter but this does not help with the table's datasource and its parameter. Any help would be appreciated.

this.table1.DataSource = "GetLocationsData";

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the available values source and most probably filters:

```
Telerik.Reporting.ReportParameter reportParameter1 = new Telerik.Reporting.ReportParameter();
this.csvDataSource1 = new Telerik.Reporting.CsvDataSource();
this.table1 = new Telerik.Reporting.Table();
    
this.csvDataSource1.Source = "id,text\r\n1,a\r\n2,b\r\n3,c";
this.table1.DataSource = this.csvDataSource1;
this.table1.Filters.Add(new Telerik.Reporting.Filter("= Fields.text", Telerik.Reporting.FilterOperator.Equal, "= Parameters.paramString.Value"));
reportParameter1.AvailableValues.DataSource = this.csvDataSource1;
reportParameter1.AvailableValues.ValueMember = "=Fields.Text";
reportParameter1.Name = "paramString";
reportParameter1.Text = "String";
reportParameter1.Value = "a";
reportParameter1.Visible = true;
this.ReportParameters.Add(reportParameter1);
```

If this does not help you, you can have a look at the available reports that come with the installation - replace in the path below your Telerik Reporting version, mine is R3 2022. View Code (F7) on the report's designer.cs file:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Progress\Telerik Reporting R3 2022\Examples\CSharp\.NET Framework\ReportLibrary
```

Another option if you are stuck, is to create the report in the Visual Studio Designer and View the generated code (F7) on the yourreportname.designer.cs file.
If the report was created using the [web report or standalone report designer](https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/designing-reports/report-designer-tools/overview) you can [import](https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/designing-reports/report-designer-tools/desktop-designers/tools/report-wizards/import-report-wizard) the report definition file (trdp, trdx, trbp) into Visual Studio (will be converted to type definition .cs file) first.

Reference:
https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/designing-reports/connecting-to-data/report-parameters/how-to-add-report-parameters
https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/designing-reports/connecting-to-data/report-parameters/overview